# Function for sum of reciprocals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Does there exist a function $Q$ such that
$$
\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dots=Q(a+b+c+\dots)
$$

where $a,b,c,\dots\in\Bbb{R}$

Comment: No, because it fails to be well-defined.

Comment: @user296602 First of all, thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate (for this specific case)? I have not yet come across the notion of "well-defined".

Comment: $Q(1) = Q(1/2 + 1/2) = 2 + 2 = 4$, and $Q(1) = Q(.9 + .1) = 10/9 + 10$. These are not compatible.

Comment: @user296602 Wow. This is cool. Thanks I get it now.

Comment: Of course not.  What would the value of $Q(2)$ be?  What would the value of $Q(1+1)$ be?  Note that $1+1=2$.